# jQuery and Ci not properly processing a logout feature

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Am I doing something wrong with the following code? I can't seem to get alert("success") to process when the Ci session expires. Below is my jquery and Ci code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/sessionExpire", function(data) {
        var sessionState = jQuery.parseJSON('{"sessionExpired":"true","sessionExpired":"false"}');
        if(sessionState.sessionExpired === "true") { // if session is expired run the following code
            var dataString = 'true';
            jQuery.ajax({   // send the expired signal to Ci so that it knows the session has expired
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/extendSession',
                data: {'dataString': true},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.extendedSession == true) {
                        alert('success');
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if(sessionState.sessionExpired == "false") {
            return;
        }
    });
}, 120000); // loop through every 2 minutes
```

CodeIgniter Code:

```
public function sessionExpire() {
        if ($this->session->userdata("logged") == "1") {
            echo json_encode(array("sessionExpired" => false));
        } elseif($this->session->userdata("logged") == "0") {
            echo json_encode(array("sessionExpire" => true));
        }
    } public function extendSession() {
        // set loggedIn session var
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged', '1');
        // return json to ajax call
        echo json_encode(array("extendedSession" => true));
    }
```

Comment: `var sessionState = jQuery.parseJSON('{"sessionExpired":"true","sessionExpired":"false"}');` here may be one of the problems..

Comment: `sessionState.sessionExpired` always will be `false`

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON('{"sessionExpired":"true","sessionExpired":"false"}');` return first `sessionExpired = true` and second `sessionExpired = false`, which overwrite the first.

Comment: Oh okay, so do I need to place false first or do i need to structure it differently?

Comment: You need to structure differently. Will post a answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Your tring to manipulate a session timeout on the frontend ! really ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.parseJSON('{"sessionExpired":"true","sessionExpired":"false"}');` return first `sessionExpired = true` and second `sessionExpired = false`, which overwrite the first.

So, here is one way to do this (need test):

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/sessionExpire", function(data) {
        if(data.sessionExpired == "true") { // if session is expired run the following code
            // var dataString = 'true'; // Remove this
            jQuery.ajax({   // send the expired signal to Ci so that it knows the session has expired
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/extendSession',
                data: {'dataString': true},
                success: function(data) {
                    //if (data.extendedSession == true) {
                        alert('success');
                    //} else {
                    //    return false;
                    //}
                    // Remove commented code, because extendSession() always return true
                }
            });
        } else {
            return 'Session not expired!';
        }
    });
}, 120000); // loop through every 2 minutes
```

And CI functions:

```
public function sessionExpire()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata("logged") == "1") {
        echo json_encode(array("sessionExpired" => false));
    } elseif ($this->session->userdata("logged") == "0") {
        echo json_encode(array("sessionExpired" => true));
    }
}

public function extendSession()
{
    // set loggedIn session var
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged', '1');
    // return json to ajax call
    echo json_encode(array("extendedSession" => true));
}
```

Comment: Now what happens if it returns false? how do i know when it returns false?

Comment: `extendSession` always return `true`, which make unnecessary some part of codes..

Comment: With your code, how would else statement in the return function know that it is returning false

Comment: Because I know the function `sessionExpire` return only `true` and `false`, so, if the `data.sessionExpired` is not true, need to be false. I updated my code with some of unnecessary lines.

Comment: Okay cool. thanks man. I am going to let it sit for awhile till the session expires and see what all it does